# Android sqlite query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,lastname FROM people WHERE lastname=null; ",null);
```

this query does not return the members whose lastname is empty. What is wrong with that query ? Should I check like that WHERE lastname="" ?

Comment: have you tried lastname=''? (empty string)

Comment: A comment since I'm not sure exactly what you're doing: if you're trying to access the Contacts database, you should be using the built in ContentProvider classes.  They're the recommended way to handle this in Android.

Comment: There are some simple implementations of SQL Lite for your PC.  Much quicker to test and debug queries than compiling and testing you Android app...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
    ... WHERE lastname IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to test for `NULL` values with comparison operators, such as `=`, `<`, etc.

You have to use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators instead.

```
SELECT id, lastname FROM people WHERE lastname IS NULL;
```